# Cannot convert IntStream to some Object Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use an `IntStream` to instantiate a stream of objects:

```
Stream<MyObject> myObjects = 
       IntStream
        .range(0, count)
        .map(id -> new MyObject(id));
```

But it says that it cannot convert `MyObject` to `int`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The [`IntStream` class's `map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) maps `int`s to more `int`s, with a `IntUnaryOperator` (`int` to `int`), not to objects.

Generally, all streams' `map` method maps the type of the stream to itself, and `mapToXyz` maps to a different type.

Try the [`mapToObj` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) instead, which takes an `IntFunction` (`int` to object) instead.

```
.mapToObj(id -> new MyObject(id));
```

Comment: Or `.mapToObj(MyObject::new)`…

Answer (score 10):

```
Stream stream2 = intStream.mapToObj( i -> new ClassName(i));
```

This will convert the `intstream` to `Stream` of specified object type, `mapToObj` accepts a function.

There is method `intStream.boxed()` to convert intStream directly to `Stream<Integer>`